# python spec works differently as mentioned in the documentation

Tags: python-3.x

```
>>> from mock import *
>>> from urllib import request
>>> mock = Mock(spec=request.Request)
>>> mock.has_data()
<mock.Mock object at 0x...>
>>> mock.has_data.assret_called_with()
```

From : https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#autospeccing

1) How can the statement "mock.has_data()" work as it throws error on my system ?
I do not find has_data() mentod in the request library.

2) Assuming even if we have "has_data()", I doubt how the below call works and doesnt throw attirbute error ?

Eg: mock.has_data.assret_called_with()

In my case with below example it fails but above mentioned example in python documentation doesn't report any error

```
from mock import *
from urllib import request
mock = Mock(spec=request.Request)
mock.has_header()
mock.has_header.assret_called_with()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\test2.py", line 5, in <module>
    mock.has_header.assret_called_with()
  File "C:\Users\hai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\mock\mock.py", line 703, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: assret_called_with
```

Please clarify, Is something wrong with my understanding or wrong with the documentaion ?

Answer (score 0):

The example in the documentation is outdated (it is a bug. [You can help fixing it](https://devguide.python.org/docquality/)). It worked as described in Python 3.3. `mock.has_data()` should raise AttributeError in [Python 3.4+](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#request-objects):

> Changed in version 3.4: The request methods add_data, has_data, get_data, get_type, get_host, get_selector, get_origin_req_host and is_unverifiable that were deprecated since 3.3 have been removed.

The documentation should use a method that exists on `request.Request` object (such as `mock.has_header()`). The point is to illustrate the difference between `mock.nonexisting` (raises `AttributeError` if `request.Request` has no such attribute) and `mock.some_existing_attribute.some_nonexisting_attribute` (the latter doesn't raise `AttributeError` even if `mock.some_existing_attribute` has no `some_nonexisting_attribute` attribute):

```
>>> from unittest.mock import Mock
>>> from urllib import request
>>> mock = Mock(spec=request.Request)
>>> mock.has_header()  # there is request.Request.has_header
<Mock name='mock.has_header()' id='174952746'>
>>> mock.nonexisting   # there is no request.Request.nonexisting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/...python3.6/unittest/mock.py", line 582, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("Mock object has no attribute %r" % name)
AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute 'nonexisting'
Mock object has no attribute 'nonexisting'
>>> mock.has_header.nonexisting   # no exception but there is no has_header.nonexisting
<Mock name='mock.has_header.nonexisting' id='249631353'>
```

In other words, `spec` is not recursive.